# How to enable only part of the api for Sockend on cote?

Tags: cote

In documentation it is shown that when user creates socket connection, it can create namespace:

`let socketNamespaced = io.connect('/rnd');`

for `sockend.js` server initialization there is no mention of namespace.

```
const sockend = new cote.Sockend(io, {
    name: 'Sockend',
    // key: 'a certain key'
});
```

From what I understand, client chooses to which namespace to connect. Now, to avoid security issues, is there a way to enforce socket namespace on server side.

For example

```
const sockend = new cote.Sockend(io, {
    name: 'Sockend',
    namespace: '/cmd'
});
```

That way, only this namespace will be exposed to socket and there would be no chance of changing the client namespace and opening up the entire api to sockend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the namespace in the Responder. Using the property `respondsTo` you then define what types are exposed publicly by Sockend:

```
var cmdResponder = new cote.Responder({
  name: 'CMD Responder',
  namespace: 'cmd',
  respondsTo: [ 'hello' ]
})
cmdResponder.on('hello', async(req) => { return 'hi' })
```

Without `respondsTo` set in Responders the Sockend exposes no types by itself.

In this example, the `/cmd` namespace would **only** answer to 'hello'.